# OpenEditor ProjectPath

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide

I am trying to open the Eclipse Editor by using the java classname only, for ie. my.Package.Editor.ShowSourceCode.java.
My Problem is that I cannot find any hint on how to open the IDE Editor with the java class path and not the OS-Path. The following is a code example which doesn't work, but should give some kind of a hint on how it should work.

`IProject p= workspace.getRoot().getProject("my.Package.Editor");
IFile f = p.getFile("ShowSourceCode.java"); 
IEditorPart editor = IDE.openEditor(page, f);`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no support for this.

Comment: Hi greg,Thanks, for your answer. So what you mean is that I cannot open the Editor in some way by only passing in my.Package.Editor.ShowSourceCode.java? So every solution to achieve this would work for me. I mean if there I have to use an Ifile or an Ipath would work for me as well for now.

Comment: You can't do this with IFile or IPath as they don't know anything about classpaths. You would have to look at the Eclipse JDT code to see how things like the 'Open Type' dialog work.